# Is main.js basically the same as index.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using the command `npx create-react-app my-app` to build a new React app environment. It creates a simple and generic app with the React logo. It generates folders such as `public` with `index.html` and `src` with your typical files such as `App.css`, `App.js`, and `index.js`, among others.

While studying the code for reverse engineering purposes I noticed that some projects have a file called `main.js`. I assume people are manually creating this file and input code similar to pre-populated `index.js` code (automatically created by `npx create-react-app my-app`). Essentially code for routing or calling components which gets rendered.

Are these two file names interchangeable or should they serve different purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name for the JS file you use as your entry point is arbitrary. Your bundler’s (Webpack, Parcel, etc) configuration will determine which file it looks for.